# Joining multiple tables in sql-server

Tags: sql-server

I have not much experience in sql, and I can't solve a problem:

I need records from one table where there is a specific match or no match to an other table.

Precisely: I have four tables:

table 1 (nevlista): nevID, nev -- theese are names

table 2 (regikod): nevID, regikod, csoport -- theese are codes and groups like: 1-100-A, 1-102-B, 2-302-A, 2-402-B, 2-502-C,....

table 3 (nkhk): nevID, ktghelyID, and dates

table 4 (koltseghely): ktghelyID, csoport

I need this query: those names from table1 who are in an ktghelyID from date x to date y (in table 3) and if they have a code in table 2, then the code from there where the group is the same as the group of the ktghelyID in table 4. I have this code:

```
  select nevlista.nevID, nevlista.nev, nkhk.ktghelyID, regikod.regikod, regikod.csoport from nevlista
inner join nkhk on nevlista.nevID = nkhk.nevID
left outer join regikod on nevlista.nevID = regikod.nevID
inner join koltseghely on nkhk.ktghelyID = koltseghely.ktghelyID
where nkhk.ktghelyID = 21
and nkhk.khkezddatum <= '2017-12-01'
and (nkhk.khvegedatum is null or (nkhk.khvegedatum <= '2017-12-31' and not nkhk.khvegedatum <= '2017-12-01'))
```

This gives following result:

```
nevID  ktghelyID  regikod  csoport
91200   21        91200    Lin DE
90938   21        671      Lin DE
91199   21        91199    Lin DE
91136   21        751      Lin DE
90753   21        582      Lin DE
90753   21        1233     F
91249   21        NULL     NULL
```

So far so good, but how do I get the same list without the record before the last record (where "csoport" is F)? Where do I have to put the argument for the group? It should be "where koltseghely.csoport = regikod.csoport", but I don't know, where to place it..
Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I found out, so the question is already out of time!
it was in line 3:

```
left outer join regikod on nevlista.nevID = regikod.nevID and koltseghely.csoport = regikod csoport
```